# Printing server response in an AJAX callback (using jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have control over my server endpoint

```
@app.route('/predict', methods=['GET', 'POST', 'OPTIONS'])
@crossdomain(origin='*')

def predict():
  return 'predict12'
```

I want to return `predict12` in the callback of my AJAX call.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'https://linear-yen-140912.appspot.com/predict',
  data: 'data',
  success: function test(){console.log()},
});
```

What should I put in the `success` function so it prints `predict12`?

Comment: Try changing your success function to something like this: `success: function test(callback){console.log(callback)}`

Comment: thanks! that worked.

Comment: Did you not read the documentation for Ajax in jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: 'https://linear-yen-140912.appspot.com/predict',
data: 'data',
success: function test(result){console.log(result)},
});
```

the success has the result of the AJAX call, and thats what you should be using

Comment: callback also worked. Are result / callback special terms in JS?

Comment: what is 'callback'? result is not a special term, you can call it whatever you want.